# Assign/activate CSS class only when page is called with specfic hash/anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hash

Some areas of a web page will get a new look by new or changed CSS classes. But before the redesigned page will be public, I want to give an internal preview of the new design when the page is opened with a specific anchor, eg "http:.../public-web-site/real-webpage.html#internal-preview".

Therefore a short JavaScript should "activate" the CSS classes and styles when the URI has this anchor.
Therefore: is it possible with JavaScript (jQuery) to do this: activating the CSS classes only when the page is called with this specific anchor?

Comment: What you can do is put the css for these classes in a seperate css file, then check `window.location.hash == "#internal-preview"`, if thats true create a new link tag with the stylesheet containing the css for all of these classes in it.

Comment: Make use of the CSS [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) pseudo-class selector

Comment: Use the CSS selector [href*="internal-preview"] { css here } to style anchor tag which contains the string "internal-preview"

Comment: @j08691, wouldn't that only work for elements with [id="internal-review"]? Chrome complains about multiple elements that share an ID, versus throwing an error, but isn't applying the same ID to multiple elements still bad practice?

Comment: I don't recall advising you to re-use IDs. You can apply an ID to the body element though and create a specific set of CSS rules that use it. E.g. `body#preview h1, body#preview h2...` That way only a page where the body with that ID and the `:target` pseudo class together would apply the rules when the URL has #preview in it

Comment: Oh, durrr. That makes more sense than what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the url of the page through :

```
window.location.href
```

Then, use it to check if the anchor is attached to the string or not.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var anchor = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("#") + 1 );

if(anchor === "internal-preview") {
    // Code to activate CSS classes.
}
```

For activating CSS classes you can use following :

```
$("element_selectors").addClass("new_class");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you append ".internal-preview" to all the style changes, such that an element of identifier "canvas.main" might have reiewable changes queued under a separate block with identifier "canvas.main.internal-preview". That block takes precedence, being more specific.

As for how to switch it based on URI, you'd enqueue a listener to window with event "load" and action to be a function similar to:

```
()=>{
    window.location.href.split("#").forEach(
        (hash_appended)=>{
            if(hash_appended === "internal-preview") {
                Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*")).forEach(
                    (element)=>{element.classList.add("internal-preview");}
                );
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Note that I made that a forEach call rather than a simple loop. This would allow multiple such tags to be used simultaneously, in case you wanted to use other such flags on the same page. If you have no such intent, it would become:

```
()=>{
    if(window.location.href.split("#")[1] === "internal-review"){
        Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("*")).forEach(
            (element)=>{element.classList.add("internal-preview");}
        );
    }
}
```

You could do similar things in jQuery, but it isn't required. This is a pure native solution.

Comment: I just realized that this may not cover cases where you're appending children somewhere in the document, after the "load" event fires. Those new children may potentially lack the new class. If that represents a difficult use-case, the MDN page on MutationObserver has a clean demonstration on how to enqueue actions on DOM manipulation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver